# C# convert string value to display with thousands separators

Tags: c#

I'm receiving a string value (for example "331000110.00") and I want to convert it so it has thousands separators (I want to have something like this: 331 000 110.00). Important thing is that I want this field to stay as a string. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Comment: `Decimal.Parse("331000110.00").ToString("#,0.00");`